# TypeScript - function return type based on parameter type

Tags: typescript

I got some interfaces like this:

```js
export interface BroadcastChannel {
  name: string;
  payload: Record<string, unknown>;
}

export interface TaskWindowCloseChannel extends BroadcastChannel {
  name: 'TASK_WINDOW_CLOSE';
  payload: {
    taskId: number;
  };
}

export interface WindowFocusChannel extends BroadcastChannel {
  name: 'WINDOW_FOCUS';
  payload: {
    windowName: string;
  };
}
```

Which will be used in a function:

```js
public listenChannel<T extends BroadcastChannel>(name:  T['name']): Observable<T> {
  const obs = new Subject<T>();
  const bc = new BroadcastChannel(name);
  bc.onmessage = (ev) => obs.next(ev.data);

  return obs.asObservable();
}
```

I would like to have a typing logic on this function that whenever I put `'TASK_WINDOW_CLOSE'` or any other value of `name` property in previous interfaces, I'll have the return type of the function typed with the correct `payload` property type in the observable.

And I want to avoid overloads because in the future there will be plenty of these TaskWindowChannel-like interfaces.

So the ideal output would be:

```js
listenChannel('TASK_WINDOW_CLOSE').subscribe((data: { taskId: number }) => {}); // data type is inferred by name param
listenChannel('WINDOW_FOCUS').subscribe((data: { windowName: string }) => {}); // data type is inferred by name param
```

Comment: You probably want a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#discriminating-unions) on the name property. Although I'm not sure you can get what you want since your function can accept arbitrary extensions of your interface which are not knowable at compile-time.

Comment: Please consider either tagging this with rxjs or removing the dependency on `Observable`/`Subject`.  Ideally someone could take your code and drop it into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link)](https://tsplay.dev/WJ8qkN) and reproduce your issue for themselves.

Comment: `listenChannel<TaskWindowCloseChannel>()`? Seems like that would clarify the intent better than a string.

Comment: The discriminated union solution looks like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wjJZMw) but without a dependency-free [mcve] I'm not sure if it works for you.

Comment: First, sorry for the dependency-free question, RxJS was not something useful in my example because I only needed the return type. Second, your discriminated union solution looks really good and it's what I'm looking for, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't implement this directly. However, you can utilize an interface that "links" your payload and your names

```
interface TaskWindowClosePayload{
    taskId: number,
}

interface WindowFocusPayload {
    windowName: string,
}

interface MapPayloadNameToType { 
    'TASK_WINDOW_CLOSE': TaskWindowClosePayload,
    'WINDOW_FOCUS': WindowFocusPayload,
}; 

interface MyBroadcastChannel<T extends keyof MapPayloadNameToType> {
    name: T;
    payload: MapPayloadNameToType[T]; 
}
```

Now you can use const strings as parameters:

```
function foo<T extends keyof MapPayloadNameToType>(name: T): MyBroadcastChannel<T> {
    return null as any; // implement and make sure this is correct at runtime!
}

foo('TASK_WINDOW_CLOSE').payload.taskId;
```

The idea is to have a type where the properties are your channel names and the types of the properties are the types of the payload of that channel. They `keyof` keyword can then be used to get those keys as a union type.

Also take a look at [the comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68531894/typescript-function-return-type-based-on-parameter-type#comment121116123_68531894) by jcalz who goes the opposite route: Building the name-type mapping type from a union type.

You can add some convenience by introducing more types like `type ChannelNames = keyof MapPayloadNameToType` but that would make the example more complex.

Comment: I'd suggest changing `map` to a more conventional type name like `PayloadMap` or something; lowercase names like `map` tend to imply "this is a variable name" and not "this is an interface name"

Comment: Yes, absolutely. I just happened to talk about this with colleagues and still had some play-around-code in my typescript playground that I could copy over. I have improved the answer now.